# Unable to compile UWP with .Net Native in release mode

Tags: uwp-xaml, .net-native

I am getting error whilst compiling a UWP using .Net Native in release build

I setup by `default.rd.xml` like this, I thought some of these error (`error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Duration', Windows.UI.Xaml.GridLength`) below should not have come as I have defined `<Namespace Name="Windows.UI.Xaml" Dynamic="Required All" />` `in default.rd.xml`.

```
<Directives xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2013/01/metadata">
  <Application>
    <Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />
    <Type Name="Windows.Foundation.TypedEventHandler{Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.TabView,Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.TabViewTabCloseRequestedEventArgs}" MarshalObject="Public" />
    <Type Name="Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.TabView">
      <Event Name="TabCloseRequested" Dynamic="Required"/>
    </Type>

    <Type Name="Windows.Foundation.TypedEventHandler{Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeView,Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeViewItemInvokedEventArgs}" MarshalObject="Public" />

    <Type Name="Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeView">
      <Event Name="ItemInvoked" Dynamic="Required"/>
    </Type>

    <Namespace Name="Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls" Dynamic="Required All" />
    <Namespace Name="Windows.UI.Xaml" Dynamic="Required All" />
    <Namespace Name="Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" Dynamic="Required All" />
    <Namespace Name="Microsoft.UI.Xaml" Dynamic="Required All" />
  </Application>

  <Library Name="ReactiveUI">
    <Assembly Name="ReactiveUI" Activate="Required All" Browse="Required All" Serialize="Required All" Dynamic="Required All" />
    <!-- See https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/1330 -->
    <Namespace Name="Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls" Dynamic="Required All" />
    <Namespace Name="Windows.UI.Xaml" Dynamic="Required All" />
    <Namespace Name="Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" Dynamic="Required All" />
    <Namespace Name="Microsoft.UI.Xaml" Dynamic="Required All" />

  </Library>

</Directives>
```

Compilation error

```
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorPosition' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.CornerRadius' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Duration' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DurationType' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.GridLength' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.GridUnitType' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.KeyTime' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.RepeatBehavior' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.RepeatBehaviorType' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Matrix' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Media3D.Matrix3D' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0005: Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>  Cleaning up unreferenced code
1>  Generating native code
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorPosition' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorPosition' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.CornerRadius' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Duration' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DurationType' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.GridLength' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.GridUnitType' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.KeyTime' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.RepeatBehavior' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.RepeatBehaviorType' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Matrix' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Media3D.Matrix3D' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.CornerRadius' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Duration' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DurationType' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.GridLength' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.GridUnitType' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.KeyTime' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.RepeatBehavior' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.RepeatBehaviorType' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Matrix' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Media3D.Matrix3D' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness' from assembly 'Windows' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly, or a dependency on a more recent Windows SDK release.
1>C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(801,5): error : ILT0005: 'C:\Users\user12\.nuget\packages\runtime.win10-x86.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.8-rel-28605-00\tools\x86\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe @"C:\Users\user12\source\Repos5\SpecEditor\src\SpecEditor\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\SpecEditor.rsp"' returned exit code 1
```

Comment: Derive from the error message your project miss assembly 'Windows', could you try to restore your app before build or delete app's bin and obj folder?

Comment: I tried it again on the azure-pipeline, where everything starts afresh. Unfortunately the same issue.

Comment: So, you build your project in Azure pipeline right? Can you build success in your local computer with visual studio?

Comment: I have tried both, its not working at either location. I have some UWP library projects too, I am wondering if they are causing the issue.

Comment: You could try to remove them and rebuild to exclude this.

Comment: I figured out, it is caused by using ReactiveUI.Event package. I have now removed it, it was more trouble than what it was worth.