# Problems with creating a local build of a UWP project

Tags: c#, .net, build, uwp, .net-native

there are some unknown problems with the local build of the UWP project. I am using visual studio 2022 with the latest version. When trying to create a build in the Release Version, I get the following errors shown in the screenshot [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doMWy.jpg). What could be the reasons for this?

I tried to build the project on a clean Workscape, build the project without .Net Native, reinstall the SDK packages. No luck.

Comment: Check this. Problem was resolved by removing ReactiveUI.Event package - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147789/unable-to-compile-uwp-with-net-native-in-release-mode

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The link you provided solves the problem by removing the ReactiveUI.Event library, which is missing in my project. So I need to look for another solution

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Can you build the project successfully in debug mode?

Comment: The problem was with the third-party library Microsoft.Azure.AppService.ApiApps.Service, which caused these errors when trying to create a build of a project. The only problem left was this: ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-arm.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2. 12-rel-31116-00\tools\ARM\alc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe @"C:\Users\Roman\source\repos\Calendar\CalendarAppointments\obj\ARM\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\CalendarAppointments. rsp"' returned exit code 1

Comment: Are you targeting x64 or X86 when you are trying to build your app?

Comment: I'm using  targeting platform X86 to build my app

Comment: I have the same issue, found no fix